# Adjectives to describe "margin of error"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

> margin of error : a small amount that is allowed for in case of miscalculation or change of circumstances.

What I commonly read is

1. **Low** margin of error
2. **Small** margin of error

Is it acceptable to use other adjectives to describe ***margin of error***? For e.g.

- Less forgiving
- avoidable
- appalling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. "Margin of error" is a noun phrase. If you want to characterize it with the adjectives "damnable" or "trivial" or "catastrophic", you can do that.